# Как отправить локальное фото через telegram api

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста формат ссылки для отправки локального фото в telegram.
Разобрался как отправить фото с сервера.

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot...../sendPhoto?chat_id=....&photo=https://d3i6fh83elv35t.cloudfront.net/static/2022/07/spacealternative-1024x593.jpg
```

Но вот, как выбрать туда фото с пк не понимаю
Пробовал указать в ссылке `file:\\\C:\file.png`
Пробовал просто `C:\file.png`
Выдаёт ошибку

```
{"ok":false,
"error_code":400,
"description":"Bad Request: invalid file HTTP URL specified: Unsupported URL protocol"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Отправлять надо не ссылку на файл, а сам файл, т.е. бинарник.

Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463102/how-to-send-photo-via-telegram-bot-with-file-path) пример для [python](/questions/tagged/python).

```python
import requests
import json

bot_token = 'BOT TOKEN'
chat_id = "CHAT ID"
file = r"C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Desktop\Capture.PNG"

files = {
    'photo': open(file, 'rb')
}

message = ('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+ bot_token + '/sendPhoto?chat_id=' 
           + chat_id)
send = requests.post(message, files = files)
```

Или [здесь](https://dev.to/rizkyrajitha/sending-images-and-more-with-telegram-bot-4c0h) через Stream для [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require("fs");
const FormData = require("form-data");

let readStream = fs.createReadStream("./image.png");

let form = new FormData();
form.append("photo", readStream);

fetch(
  `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendPhoto?chat_id=-<chat id>`,

  {
    method: "POST",
    body: form,
  }
)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

У вас какой язык? По вопросу непонятно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую, мне нужно реализовать это на JS.

Comment: А есть вариант реализовать без npm?
Используя только классический js?
Мне просто нужно что-бы по итогу запускалось всё из файла index.html

Comment: где в статье или ответе `npm`?